# Django URL Regex that allows "," "&" "=" the alphabet, and numbers

Tags: django, url

I would like a url that allows the following keys = "," "&" "=", the alphabet, and numbers.

How do I write a url that allows all of these in a single url?
I understand regex but am having a difficult time with the URL setup. So far I can only make one exception.

Comment: Did you try `[\,\&\=\w]+` ?

Comment: No, apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: It is not advisable the use of these chars in urls: they are meant for passing parameters (and you already have them in your `request.GET`)

Comment: I use it to pass parameters via Ajax to query the DB.

Comment: Actually, @don is right - you should be sending these as `GET` or `POST` and be generating the query on the server side. That way you are not exposing more than what you intend to..

Comment: You are probably right.

Comment: @DGDD If the reason you want this is to unpack a querystring, be aware that Django already does this for you. You can obtain a querystring varname with request.GET.get('varname')